# Add a checkbox to exclude possible answers of a multiple-choice question

Tags: javascript, checkbox, tampermonkey

Qconcursos.com has many multiple alternative questions, like this one:
   [qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questao/ccc0b219-43](https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questao/ccc0b219-43)

But it lacks an option to eliminate a wrong alternative (like strike-through or fade), which could be extremely helpful.
This [other site](https://questoes.olhonavaga.com.br/questoes?id=750968&tc=1) has a very neat solution (the "x" by the right of each alternative) that I would like to mimic on qconcursos.com (a simple strike-through command achievable by a checkbox would be enough).

But I have absolutely no idea on how to do that.

How could one add such a control using Tampermonkey or a some other technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that **Stack Overflow is not a script writing service**, but questions asking for such help with a website are sometimes [on topic at *Web Applications Stack Exchange*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

That said, since it is a quick easy diversion, here is **a complete working Tampermonkey script** that adds the same kind of "x" control, that the second site has, to qconcursos.com:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Qconcursos, add exclusion buttons to answers
// @match    https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/* global $ */

$("label[id^='label-alternativa']").after ( `
    <span class="tmExcludeSymb">&#x2169;</span>
` );
$(".uma-questao-corpo").on ("click", ".tmExcludeSymb", zEvent => {
    $(zEvent.target).parent ().toggleClass ("tmGrayIt");
} );

GM_addStyle ( `
    .tmExcludeSymb {
        font-weight:    bold;
        padding:        0.3ex 1em;
        cursor:         pointer;
    }
    .tmGrayIt {
        opacity:        0.35;
    }
` );
```